# Formula to Format Succeeding Rows

Tags: excel

I am trying to format the output of a report to allow me to import that data into another program. I have not found a way to manipulate the generated report into a more usable format.

The report is formatted with rows containing all the information for a certain product. If that product has additional codes/numbers that are associated with that product, they are listed in rows following the corresponding product. The problem is that those following rows are formatted completely different than the product rows they correspond with.

My goal is to concatenate all corresponding codes into Column 9, separated with commas.

A bonus would have all of the duplicates removed, but it would work even with the duplicates.

I honestly don't know if excel has the ability to achieve this, so any alternate ways to handle this would be welcome.

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 | Col7 | Col8 | Col9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 53465 | 517 | Brand1 | 083758314483 | 08375831448 | 044800 | 044800 | Supp1 |  |
| 88565 | 517 | Brand2 | 08375801599 | 08375801599 | 1599 |  | Supp2 |  |
|  |  |  | 083758015991 | 5032501599 |  |  | Supp2 |  |
| 88566 | 517 | Brand2 | 08375801799 | 08375801799 | 1799 |  | Supp2 |  |
|  |  |  | 083758017995 | 83758317996 |  |  | Supp2 |  |
| 88567 | 517 | Brand2 | 08375801999 | 08375801999 | 1999 |  | Supp2 |  |
|  |  |  | 083758019999 | 5032501999 |  |  | Supp2 |  |
| 75239 | 517 | Brand2 | 83758420009 | 083758420009 | 322200 |  | Supp2 |  |
|  |  |  | 083758432163 | 83758432163 |  |  | Supp2 |  |
|  |  |  | 083758432187 | 83758432187 |  |  | Supp2 |  |
|  |  |  | 083758432279 | 83758432279 |  |  | Supp2 |  |
|  |  |  | 083758420009 | 83758432262 |  |  | Supp2 |  |
| 53478 | 517 | Brand3 | 083758298547 | 08375829854 | 085400 | 085400 | Supp2 |  |
| 53479 | 517 | Brand3 | 083758298554 | 08375829855 | 085500 | 085500 | Supp2 |  |

Into this..

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 | Col7 | Col8 | Col9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 53465 | 517 | Brand1 | 083758314483 | 08375831448 | 044800 | 044800 | Supp1 |  |
| 88565 | 517 | Brand2 | 08375801599 | 08375801599 | 1599 |  | Supp2 | 083758015991,5032501599 |
| 88566 | 517 | Brand2 | 08375801799 | 08375801799 | 1799 |  | Supp2 | 083758017995,83758317996 |
| 88567 | 517 | Brand2 | 08375801999 | 08375801999 | 1999 |  | Supp2 | 083758019999,5032501999 |
| 75239 | 517 | Brand2 | 83758420009 | 083758420009 | 322200 |  | Supp2 | 083758432163,83758432163,083758432187,83758432187,083758432279,083758432279,083758420009,83758432262 |
| 53478 | 517 | Brand3 | 083758298547 | 08375829854 | 085400 | 085400 | Supp2 |  |
| 53479 | 517 | Brand3 | 083758298554 | 08375829855 | 085500 | 085500 | Supp2 |  |

Comment: Thank you @scott-craner for fixing my table. Could you comment on how you did it?

Comment: I just removed the three ` it is not code.

Comment: Maybe it's a permission thing then? If I try to remove the *note* and image, it will not let me save my edits. It complains that it is code still.  I give up, but thanks.

Comment: I said I gave up but it bothers me. In a private window, or even another browser I get the same thing. Just selecting __edit__ on the post without making a single change, it gives an error. https://i.imgur.com/byYcBiD.jpeg Should I report a bug?

Comment: Why in the first row of `Col9` the result is empty? Concatenation is not a difficult task, do you have any excel version constraint?

Comment: @DavidLeal If you are referring to the bottom table, it's because that product did not have addition codes to deal with. Some rows are complete as they are, others have those additional codes below that need to be concatenated into column 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following formula in cell `J2`:

```
=LET(input, A2:H15, colA, INDEX(input,,1), colDE, CHOOSECOLS(input, 4,5), colAA,
  SCAN("",colA, LAMBDA(ac,item, IF(item<>"", item, ac))),
  map, MAP(colA,LAMBDA(a, IF(a="", "",
    LET(blankRows, FILTER(colDE, (colAA=a)*(colA=""),""),
      TEXTJOIN(",",,blankRows))))),
  FILTER(HSTACK(input, map), colA<>"")
)
```

**Notes**:

- We use several `LET` calls to avoid repetition of the same element in the formula.
- If you don't have `CHOOSECOLS` available yet ([Office Insider Beta only], Windows: 2203 (Build 15104), Mac: 16.60 (220304). You can use instead: `FILTER(input, {0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0})` or just to specify the range: `D2:E15`. I prefer to have less dependency on range-specific information so the formulation is more robust. That is why I deduce it from a general variable (`input`) that contains the range.
- If you don't have `HSTACK` available you achieve the same via:
  `CHOOSE({1,2},input, map)`

and here is the output:
[image: sample excel file]

### Explanation

The main idea is to fill the blanks of any of the columns so we can search by a given column value. I am assuming **Col1** has unique values, so it is good candidate. The name: `colAA`, has the empty cells filled with previous value from **Col1**:

```
SCAN("",colA, LAMBDA(ac,item, IF(item<>"", item, ac)))
```

**Note**: It is assumed the first value of **Col1** is never empty.

Now we use `MAP` (but also `BYROW` can be used) to find the content of columns: **Col5**, **Col6** (columns `D`, `E` from the screenshot), that corresponds to a given value of **Col1**. If the value is empty, then we return an empty string, otherwise, we find the elements of the name `colDE` that corresponds to a given code (remember `colAA` has all the values filled) and the original `colA` has empty values. Once we have target subset (`blankrows`), we just need to concatenate the result delimited by `,` via `TEXTJOIN` function. The name `map` contains this result:

```
MAP(colA,LAMBDA(a, IF(a="", "",
  LET(blankRows, FILTER(colDE, (colAA=a)*(colA=""),""),
    TEXTJOIN(",",,blankRows)))))
```

In the case `colA` value is not empty but doesn't have additional blank rows, the `FILTER` function returns `#CALC!` (empty set, i.e. error) so we need to treat this special case. According to the sample data **Col9** for this case is empty, so we return an empty string (third `FILTER` input argument).

The rest is just to build the final result via `HSTACK` and remove empty rows to avoid duplicates.

Comment: This is going to take me a while to digest. I can see from your screenshot that you were able to make it work, so I've marked this as solved. This was even more difficult than I expected it would be, so thank you for taking the time to solve it!

Comment: Well it seems my 2019 version does not have the **FILTER** function. Can this be worked around?

Comment: @FRGTech I would recommend you to specify the Excel version via tag in your question next time, otherwise people assume there is no excel version constraints. If you have this version you would have more limitations than `FILTER`. Please check [here](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/functions/updates.htm) function availability by version. So the approach needs to be totally different. Most of the functions I used are not available for your version. It could be also achieved via Power Query or maybe considering a helper column.

Comment: I apologize. I honestly had no idea that they have stunted these desktop versions to force users to a subscription model. I would have specified had I known they were so terribly different. I'll be sure to specify in the future. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @FRGTech you don't have to use the desktop version, you can have a Microsoft subscription that allows you to use Excel Web with all the functionalities free of charge, up to certain storage limit. There are some functions that don't work for web version, but just a few of them such as `FILTERXML`. **This is what I am using**, it has some visual limitations, but in terms of functions almost all of them.